# Why do I see extra lines near SVG icons in print mode?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, printing

I have some SVG icons on a page, but when I try to print the page, I can see in the preview that some extra side lines will get (and are getting) printed.

[image: Sample image]

If I change the zoom level, those lines tend to disappear, but I can still see them on the actual printed paper.

The application is done in React but I don't think this has any influence, as I can see the issue reproducing the same if I look at the print preview of the SVG icon only.

I tried increasing the `viewBox` of the SVG, the size of the container element, and adding a `fill="none"` on the `<svg>` element, but nothing helped.

This is one of the icons I use in the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="33px" height="33px" viewBox="0 0 35 35" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="none">
    <defs>
        <path d="M16.5,32 C7.93958638,32 1,25.0604136 1,16.5 C1,7.93958638 7.93958638,1 16.5,1 C25.0604136,1 32,7.93958638 32,16.5 C32,25.0604136 25.0604136,32 16.5,32 Z M16.5,30 C23.9558441,30 30,23.9558441 30,16.5 C30,9.04415588 23.9558441,3 16.5,3 C9.04415588,3 3,9.04415588 3,16.5 C3,23.9558441 9.04415588,30 16.5,30 Z M22.4283814,11.3631277 L14.0480414,19.7309601 L11.3280853,17.0150634 C10.6594033,16.3731302 9.59921563,16.3835368 8.94330153,17.0384719 C8.28738743,17.6934071 8.27696531,18.7520124 8.91985804,19.4196964 L12.7728601,23.2669478 C13.5169128,23.9110174 14.6219722,23.9110174 15.3660249,23.2669478 L24.8576059,13.789533 C25.1799837,13.4678435 25.3611111,13.0314145 25.3611111,12.5763304 C25.3611111,12.1212462 25.1799837,11.6848173 24.8576059,11.3631277 C24.1866054,10.6937722 23.099382,10.6937722 22.4283814,11.3631277 Z" id="path-1"></path>
    </defs>
    <g id="Visual-/-Icons-/-Md-/-check-circle" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
            <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
        </mask>
        <use id="Shape" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
        <g id="Base-/-Colour-/-Brand-/-Primary-dark" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#009c41">
            <rect id="Rectangle-2-Copy-5" x="0" y="0" width="33" height="33"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to avoid these extra side lines when changing the zoom level or printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the rather unconventional way you are drawing this shape, you're seeing some "bleed".

Try just drawing the shape itself:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="33px" height="33px" viewBox="0 0 35 35" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="none">
    <path d="M16.5,32 C8,32 1,25 1,16.5 C1,8 8,1 16.5,1 C25,1 32,8 32,16.5 C32,25 25,32 16.5,32 Z M16.5,30 C24,30 30,24 30,16.5 C30,9 24,3 16.5,3 C9,3 3,9 3,16.5 C3,24 9,30 16.5,30 Z M22.5,11.5 L14,19.5 L11.5,17 C10.5,16.5 9.5,16.5 9,17 C8.5,17.5 8.5,18.5 9,19.5 L13,23.5 C13.5,24 14.5,24 15.5,23.5 L25,14 C25,13.5 25.5,13 25.5,12.5 C25.5,12 25,11.5 25,11.5 C24,10.5 23,10.5 22.5,11.5 Z" fill="#009c41"></path>
</svg>
```

I've also tidied up the path itself - you don't need sub-micropixel accuracy in your numbers, so I just rounded each number to the nearest half-pixel - and even that is probably overkill. Saves a lot of bytes in the long run!